# What happens to a process and/or thread while it waits on a mutex?

Tags: operating-system

When a process and/or thread waits on mutex in which state the process and/or thread is? Is it in WAIT or READY or some other state? I tried to search the answer over the web but could not find a clear, definitive answer, maybe there isn't one or maybe there is, to find out that I am posting this question here.

Comment: There can be no clear, definitive answer without a clear, definitive OS.  The mutex may spin for a few loops inthe hope that the thread holding the mutex is only, say, dequeueing a pointer and so will release the lock quickly.  It all depends on the particular implementation, which you have not given.

Answer (score 1):

*tl;dr: Nothing happens when it is waiting; it is simply a kernel data structure.*

Without loss of generality, all operating systems have some sort of model where a unit of execution (task) moves between the states : *Ready, Running, Waiting*. This Task has a data structure associated with it, where its state and registers (among other things) are recorded.

When a task moves from *Ready* to *Running*, its saved registers are loaded on a cpu, and it continues execution from its last saved state.   Initially, its saved registers are set to reasonable values for the program to start.

From *Running* to *Waiting* or *Ready*, its registers are stored in its task data structure, and this structure is placed on either a list of *Ready* or *Waiting* tasks.

From *Waiting* to *Ready*, the task data structure is removed from the *Waiting* list and appended to the *Ready* list.

When a task tries to acquire a mutex that is unavailable, it moves from *Running* (how else could it try to get the mutex) to *Waiting*.  If the mutex was available, it remains *Running*, and the mutex becomes unavailable.

When a task releases a mutex, and another task is *Waiting* for that mutex, the *Waiting* task becomes *Ready*, and acquires the mutex.  If many tasks are *Waiting*, one is chosen to acquire the mutex and become *Ready*, the rest remain *Waiting*.

This is a very abstract description; real systems are complicated by both a plurality of synchronization mechanisms (mailbox, queue, semaphore, pipe, ...), a desire to optimise the various paths, and the utilization of multiple CPUs.